# Unable to freeze Keras layers in a Tensorflow workflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to freeze Keras layers in a Tensorflow workflow. This is how I define the graph :

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import Dropout, Dense, Embedding, Flatten
from keras import backend as K
from keras.objectives import binary_crossentropy


import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()

from keras import backend as K
K.set_session(sess)

labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 1))
user_id_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 1))
item_id_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 1))



max_user_id = all_ratings['user_id'].max()
max_item_id = all_ratings['item_id'].max()

embedding_size = 30
user_embedding = Embedding(output_dim=embedding_size, input_dim=max_user_id+1,
                           input_length=1, name='user_embedding', trainable=all_trainable)(user_id_input)
item_embedding = Embedding(output_dim=embedding_size, input_dim=max_item_id+1,
                           input_length=1, name='item_embedding', trainable=all_trainable)(item_id_input)



user_vecs = Flatten()(user_embedding)
item_vecs = Flatten()(item_embedding)


input_vecs = concatenate([user_vecs, item_vecs])

x = Dense(30, activation='relu')(input_vecs)
x1 = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x2 = Dense(30, activation='relu')(x1)
y = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x2)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(binary_crossentropy(labels, y))

train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.004).minimize(loss)
```

Then I just train the model :

```
with sess.as_default():

train_step.run(..)
```

Everything is working fine when the trainable flag is set to `True`. Then when I set it to `False`, it does not freeze the layers.

I also tried to minimize only over the variable that I want to train by using `train_step_freeze = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.004).minimize(loss, var_list=[user_embedding])`, and I get :

```
('Trying to optimize unsupported type ', <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_33:0' shape=(?, 1) dtype=float32>)
```

Is it possible to use Keras layers in Tensorflow and freeze them ?

**EDIT**

In order to make things clear, I want to train the model using Tensorflow, and not by using `model.fit()`. The way to do it in Tensorflow seems to be by passing `var_list=[]` to the `minimize()` method. But I get an error while doing this :

```
('Trying to optimize unsupported type ', <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_33:0' shape=(?, 1) dtype=float32>)
```

Comment: I also want to freeze a Keras model and train the remaining layers using TensorFlow. Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: Nope, I ran into so many problems that I finally decided to use PyTorch. I would advise you to do the same. Sorry for not having an answer.

Comment: I found a way to freeze the Keras model and train only the other layers using TensorFlow. Please see my answer and let me know if it answers your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found a way to do this.

Instead of explicitly freezing the Keras model, TensorFlow gives you the option of specifying which variables you want to train.

In the following example, I instantiate a pretrained VGG16 model from Keras, define a few layers over that model, and freeze this model (that is, train only the layers following the Keras model):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16, preprocess_input
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
import numpy as np

inputs = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, 224, 224, 3))
labels = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, 1))
model = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')

features = model(preprocess_input(inputs))

# Define the further layers

conv = tf.layers.Conv2D(filters=1, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2), activation=tf.nn.relu, use_bias=True)
conv_output = conv(features)
flat = tf.layers.Flatten()
flat_output = flat(conv_output)
dense = tf.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.tanh)
dense_output = dense(flat_output)

# Define the loss and training ops

loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels, dense_output)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()

# Specify which variables you want to train in `var_list`
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, var_list=[conv.variables, flat.variables, dense.variables])
```

To use this method, you will have to instantiate an object for each layer, as that will allow you to explicitly access the variables of that layer using `layer_name.variables`. Alternatively, you can use the low level API and define your own `tf.Variable` objects and make layers using them.

You can easily verify that the above method works:

```
sess = K.get_session()
K.set_session(sess)

image = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(1, 224, 224, 3))

for _ in range(100):

    old_features = sess.run(features, feed_dict={inputs: image})
    sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={inputs: np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(2, 224, 224, 3)), labels: np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(2, 1))})
    new_features = sess.run(features, feed_dict={inputs: image})

    print(np.all(old_features == new_features))
```

This will print `True` one hundred times, meaning that the model's weights are not changing upon running the training op.

Answer (score 0):

Keras will only make layers truly untrainable if you compile the model again before training.

Now, I don't see you compile your model anywhere, and you're mixing Keras with TensorFlow commands.

If you want Keras to work properly, you must use Keras commands.

**Creating a model in Keras:**

You did the right thing up to `y`, except for defining an input layer. Before the first embedding layer, you need:

```
from keras.layers import Input

labels = Input((None, 1)) #is this really an input?????
user_id_input = Input((None, 1))
item_id_input = Input((None, 1))
```

Then you create a model in Keras:

```
from keras.models import Model

#supposing you want it to start with two inputs and the output being y
model = Model([user_id_input, item_id_input], y)
```

Then you compile your model, with the optimizer and loss you want (you must make layers untrainable before this step, or compile again whenever you change that attribute):

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

And for training, you also train with Keras commands:

```
model.fit([Xuser,Xitem],Y, epochs=..., batch_size=...., ....)
#where Xuser and Xitem are actual training input data and Y contains the actual labels.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and pointing out the problem ! The issue is that I don't want to compile the model and train it with Keras but I want to use Tensorflow to train the model. How could I freeze the layers then ?

The reason why I want to train it with Tensorflow is because I'm running this model in a website, and I cannot use Keras because it will bug whenever the model is queried twice at the same time.

Comment: I'm afraid you have to search for that in tensorflow documentation.

Comment: Yes that's exactly why I also tried to minimize only over the variable that I want to train by using `train_step_freeze = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.004).minimize(loss, var_list=[user_embedding])`. I got an error that I specified in the question. I'll update my question then, in order to ask for the solution to this specific error.